# Python: how to calculate in-degree and out-degree distribution from a networkx Graph

Tags: python, networkx

I created a directed graph using the `networkx` package.

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
```

In order to compute the degree distribution I just do:

```
x = list(nx.degree(G).values())
counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(x)
```

How can I get the `in_degree` and `out_degree` distributions?

Answer (score 1):

Call `G.in_degree` and `G.out_degree` instead of `nx.degree`.